# How to check the type of file to be downloaded from a link

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to download a file from a link using the following line of code:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmcgBRy',f'{UNKNOWN_FACES_DIR}\\sample2.mp4')
```

But the thing is I don't know what type of file is stored in the link and hence cant give an appropriate file extension before downloading it.

Is there any way to get to know the type of file i.e. .jpg, .jpeg, .mp4 etc. before downloading it?

Comment: You could perform a `HEAD` request separately and examine th  `Content-Type:` header, but dong that before downloading is less efficient and less robust. Better just to download to a temporary file, then rename once you have the headers *and* the payload safely retrieved. (On real operating systems, the extension is quite separate from the file type, but of course, the extension can help a human determine the file's type, and anyway, you seem to be in Windows limbo.)

Comment: Why don't you download the file, then rename it based on what the file type turns out to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pure urllib, you can get the content type from the following:

```py
import urllib
url = 'https://i.imgur.com/Woi6pwf.jpg' 
urllib.request.urlopen(url).info()['content-type']
```

which returns:
`'image/jpeg'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Python-Magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) to find the MIME-type of the file. I guess this is the best library to be used for this purpose. You can do like this

```
import magic
magic.from_file("testdata/test.pdf")

# OUTPUT
# >>> 'PDF document, version 1.2'
```

**Recommended Version**

```
import magic
magic.from_buffer(open("testdata/test.pdf").read(2048))

# OUTPUT
# >>> 'PDF document, version 1.2'
```